# D3JS - Not able to align the word cloud in a page

Tags: html, d3.js

I am trying to align word cloud inside the window only. Please find the screenshot . It is moving out of the window and some part of it is getting hidden.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud).  Could you post some of your code and some ideas on what might be causing the problem?  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) may be helpful for sharing your code & replicating the issue.

Comment: If you want to try to use jsfiddle, I set up an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ybxUC/1/).  You might be able to re-create the issue by dropping some of your code into that example.

Comment: I am taking values from CSV. I would have words and their size. Size is sometimes more than 1000. Sometimes less than 100. I will normalize it using clamp. But it is moving beyond my screen. I dont know how to upload csv and get it working. http://jsfiddle.net/MadhuSathish/Xxb8m/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MadhuSathish/CDf5q/1/ When I try to add more words into your fiddle also, it is going out of boundary. It is out of screen boundary. Can you please tell me how to make everything align inside this window.

Comment: Yep, if you try plugging some more words into the example I posted from the [github site](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html), the words do extend beyond the canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/ybxUC/4/.  The answer seems to be in adjusting the canvas size, `translate` parameters, and word size so that your words fit within the specified dimensions, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ybxUC/6/

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. It works great. I am not able to figure out how it works. Is it omitting words of bigger font?

Comment: The size for each word is being randomly generated in this example, `10 + Math.random() * 20`.  If you change that to a static `10`, you'll see that the words become the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing around with the word cloud and am a bit of a newbie to JS.
But if you change the following line in your fiddle code from this:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
```

to this below then it won't go out of bounds.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(300,300)")
```